# How to unlink a vertex group from Armature?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

So, I have a mesh, and I only want some of the vertices not affected by the armature. I know I can weight paint, but I constantly do automatic weight since I do a lot of changes. Is there a way to tell the armature not to link with a certain vertex group no matter how many times I do automatic weights?

Answer (score 1):

When the vertex group is empty, lock it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!